# No option to cast int to date or date to int using standard (not legacy)

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a function to cast INT to DATE or DATE to INT for timestamp filtering?

Is see no such function in Google BigQuery datetype pages.

Below is the query i had made for a public dataset for testing:

```
SELECT title, comment, contributor_username FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia] WHERE wp_namespace = 3 AND timestamp = ??
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M94uR.png)

As shown in the image in attached link, the timestamp column is INT datetype.

Comment: It's slightly confusing that your title specifies that you want standard SQL, but you've given a query in legacy SQL. I've provided an answer assuming you really *do* want standard SQL, but you might want to edit your sample query accordingly. (I'd also suggest reformatting it to avoid scrolling.)

Comment: hi, since i am new with big query, I never knew whats the different syntax with legacy and standard. I will be using standard though, you guess it right :) thank you very much.. but do you know of a link of where all standard SQL function is listed?

Comment: actually i found the list :) lack of research,.. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want [`UNIX_SECONDS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#unix_seconds) to convert a timestamp to the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, and [`TIMESTAMP_SECONDS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_seconds) to convert a number of seconds since the Unix epoch into a `TIMESTAMP`.

(I'm guessing that the integer value you've got *is* a number of seconds since the Unix epoch. That would work for the value you've shown, if it's meant to represent a timestamp in March 2007.)

Here's a sample to show 10 contributions from March 2007:

```
SELECT title, comment, contributor_username, TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.wikipedia`
WHERE
  wp_namespace = 3
  AND timestamp >= UNIX_SECONDS('2007-03-01T00:00:00Z')
  AND timestamp < UNIX_SECONDS('2007-04-01T00:00:00Z')
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For Unix time (in your example), use Daisy's answer.
However if in other cases you want `DATE(2018,01,01)` to be `20180101` (integer) you can use `CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) AS INT64)`.
For `TIMESTAMP`, use `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP`